# Partially overlap elements using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'd like to partially overlap multiple HTML elements - say DIVs - as in the below image. The black-bordered rectangles ([Hanafuda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanafuda) cards) represent the elements I want to overlap.

[image]

With Javascript I'm sure I could come up with something, but I'd like to know if there's a pure CSS solution. I considered relative positioning but the problem is that each card needs a bigger and bigger offset along the x-axis.

Ideally I'd like the degree of overlap to depend on how much space there is, so that the elements crowd together more when cramped, but that's secondary and I don't mind using JS to accomplish it.

Comment: I can only think of CSS preprocessor or nested tags without JS.

Comment: You can do this using absolute positioning, overflow values and z-index.  Depending on specifics, media queries might be able to handle the changing of the degree of overlap.

Comment: The first requirement (just overlapping) can be done just with negative margins and display: inline-block

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve that using flex, making all cards except the last one adjust to the remaining space

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rgnLmajh/1/) of the below:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
}
.card-container {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.card-container:last-child {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.card {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ccc 0%, #444 100%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Watch out for flex compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), but this works nicely and [the overlap changes with the parent width](http://jsfiddle.net/7unq1qm1/) if desired.

Comment: How can I add a padding/margin/gap between the cards that disappears as the cards overlap?

Answer (score 3):

This can also be achieved using `display: table`, which currently enjoys greater browser compatibility over the newer, and wonderful, flex specification.

**Compatibility:** [IE8+ and all modern browsers.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table)

- The outer div is given `display: table`
- Each image is wrapped in a div with `display: table-cell`
- `table-layout: fixed` allows the "cells" to overlap
- The outer div can be kept flexible to allow the images to overlap more / less depending on the space they left with

### Full Example

```css
.cards {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 700px;
}
.cards > div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
}
.cards > div > img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x300" /></div>
  <div><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x300/FF0000" /></div>
  <div><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x300" /></div>
  <div><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x300/FF0000" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the simplest solution was to use `float: left` combined with a negative `right-margin`:

```css
.card {
  --card-width: 100px;

  margin-right: calc(25px - var(--card-width));
  float: left;
  
  width: var(--card-width);
  height: calc(var(--card-width) * 1.5);
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```