# Is it possible to make divs overlap like cards *just* using css

Tags: css

Currently my site looks like this (making a browser based card game), please ignore the art for now - [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGHt7.png) - I would like them to overlap slightly rather than wrapping around and creating a new line almost like someone is holding the cards. I have no idea where to even start with this without using js so I was wondering if anyone could help me come up with a solution that just uses pure css solution.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users read [ask] and take the [tour] for tips on writing questions that best enable the community to provide assistance. Please note it is generally expected that you will provide a [mcve] in code in the body of the question to provide context specific to your problem. Additionally, in a case like this, it might be prudent to include some visual mock-up of the desired outcome, as the description provided has some ambiguities. Also, [this may be a dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31128349/6831341); if not, please explain why. Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margin-left` and `margin-right` with negative values. Or you can set the card positions by using `position: absolute` and `left` and `top` properties.